# MakeFile : Header in different Directory - Error

Tags: c++, makefile

I am trying to avoid relative paths in header declaration of C++ files. So, I had used the makefile by following an online example. But I am getting error. Please check the code and help me to resolve this

```
COMPILER = g++
IDIR = ./include
CXXFLAGS += -I$(IDIR)
CFLAGS += -I$(IDIR)

EXEC = hello
OBJECTS = main.o factorial.o hello.o

all: $(EXEC)

(---- I had also used CFLAGS instead of CXXFLAGS below but the same result###)

$(EXEC): $(OBJECTS)
    $(COMPILER) $(CXXFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $(EXEC)  

main.o: main.cpp ./include/functions.h 
    $(COMPILER) $(CXXFLAGS) -c main.cpp

factorial.o: main.cpp ./include/functions.h 
    $(COMPILER) $(CXXFLAGS) -c factorial.cpp

hello.o: main.cpp ./include/functions.h 
    $(COMPILER) $(CXXFLAGS) -c hello.cpp
```

Error:

make: *** No rule to make target 'include / functions.h "
   required by "main.o" to create. Closing.

Directory Structure is

```
- main.cpp
- factorial.cpp
- hello.cpp
- MakeFile.mk
- +include (dir) 
      ----->functions.h
```

main.cpp contains ----include "functions.h"---- in the header declaration

Comment: This is a pure `make` error message. The error is not related to the content of any .cpp or .h file. The error actually can come only from the content of the Makefile, and the presence or absence of the files named in it. As this, `make` states that it cannot find the file `include/functions.h`. Double check it actually is here, with correct name and matching case.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But I am using the same directory structure as mentioned in the post and I had checked the spelling, matching case, but everything seems to be as shown in the post. I am still obtaining the same error

Comment: Just to check, is the `+` part of the name of the `+include` directory?

Comment: For debugging purpose you could add the following lines to your Makefile: `./include/functions.h:` and `\ttouch $@`. (Where `\t` is a tab character.) It will instruct `make` to create an empty include/functions.h file if it's missing.

Comment: I just kept + to identify it as a directory in the post. Can you please give me the above command once.

Comment: See in the answers, it helps with correct formatting.

Comment: @DidierTrosset Thanks a lot ,touch command has helped me. functions.h was written as functoins.h.... and you are dead right from the first. I had missed this even after I checked it, I should be more careful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using h files as a source files.
there should only be:

`main.o: main.cpp

    $(COMPILER) $(CXXFLAGS) -c main.cpp`

edited:

I copy your folder content and write simple application where hello.cpp have a simple void function, factorial.cpp have simple int-returning function ane main.cpp have int main() and uses this functions, include.h hafe declarations of these two dummy functions.
Now. My makefile looks:

```
COMPILER = g++
IDIR = ./include
CXXFLAGS += -I$(IDIR)
EXEC =  hello
OBJECTS =  main.o factorial.o hello.o

all: $(EXEC)

$(EXEC): $(OBJECTS)
        $(COMPILER) $(CXXFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $(EXEC)

main.o: main.cpp factorial.o hello.o
    $(COMPILER) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $@

factorial.o: factorial.cpp
    $(COMPILER) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $@

hello.o: hello.cpp
    $(COMPILER) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

[download for my sample](http://www.speedyshare.com/QV9kZ/sample.tar.gz)

That should help You!

Comment: Thank you for the reply. When I had changed accordingly I am getting this error
g++ -I./include -c main.cpp
main.cpp:2:23:fatal error: functions.h: File or directory not found

Comment: Yep, but u have specify a header file. U have to have -I./include/functions.h   so change IDIR = ./include to IDIR = ./include/functions.h

Comment: Thank you I had done the same Now I am getting 

g++ -I./include/functions.h -c main.cpp
main.cpp:2:23:fatal error: functions.h: File or directory not found

But the same error is coming

Comment: ` main.cpp:2:23:fatal error: functions.h: File or directory not found`

Comment: You don't provide -o main.o in yours `main.o: main.cpp
$(COMPILER) $(CXXFLAGS) -c main.cpp`

Comment: Approve answer if I helped you, please:)

Answer (score 0):

This is a pure `make` error message. The error is not related to the content of any .cpp or .h file. The error actually can come only from the content of the Makefile, and of the presence or absence of the files named in it.

As per this error message, `make` states that it cannot find the file `include/functions.h`. Double check it actually is here, with correct name and matching case.

For debugging purpose you can add the following lines to your Makefile:

```
./include/functions.h:
    touch $@
```

It will instruct make to create an empty include/functions.h file if it's missing.